# How do you encode Hebrew characters to a database without getting "????"

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

When I insert Hebrew words to the database, I get ????? marks after i click "show Table" in Server Explorer.

Is there a way to Encode the hebrew letters before they go in?

```
 sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@HebrewLettersEncoded", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        sqlCommand.Parameters["@HebrewLettersEncoded"].Value = HebrewLettersTextBox1Output.Text;
```

I am thinking that there should be some encoder that will encode - HebrewLettersTextBox1Output.Text

Comment: Keep in mind that even after you've properly stored them (nvarchar) they may still appear as "????" in some SQL management tools - this is because the font used doesn't always include Hebrew characters. Missing glyphs will be rendered as ? or a square.

Comment: hmmm, anyway to overcome this?

Comment: Depending on your version of windows there are various options for installing Hebrew language packs.  A google search of those key words should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make sure the field you are trying to put the characters into is an NVarChar  (not varchar).  Then change the code above to....:

```
 sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@HebrewLettersEncoded", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
```

Comment: very nice. So now i wont have problems extracting the Hebrew words with SqlReader..convert them to string and compare against another string?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want an **n**varchar field instead of a varchar.  Hebrew characters aren't in plain ASCII, so you'll need unicode to represent them, unless you want to do ugly code page selection.

Comment: Thank you, i wish i could give two best answers